# Rails / Memcached Error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached

I'm running into an issue using memcached with Rails 3.2.11 and Dalli 2.6.4 on Heroku. Memcached works great in development, but when I push to a staging environment on Heroku I'm running into the following error when I hit the cached page or when I write `Rails.cache.clear` in the console:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/server.rb:35:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:334:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:334:in `block in ring'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:326:in `map'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:326:in `ring'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:238:in `flush'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:196:in `block in clear'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:291:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:291:in `instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:195:in `clear'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:88:in `clear'
from (irb):1
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The relevant parts of `staging.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, nil,
{:namespace => 'STAGING', :expires_in => 1.day.to_i, :compress => true }

config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = nil
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the problem was, but switching to using Dalli 1.1.5 fixed everything.